# Are there any quantum mechanical systems where the position vector lives in a finite dimensional Hilbert Space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

I don't have much to add to the title. Are there any quantum mechanical systems where the position vector lives in a finite dimensional Hilbert Space? If so, please provide example(s).

Comment: Hard to take the question literally. Position is an observable... But in certain formalisms De Sitter space might provide an example.

Comment: Can I decree that a component of spin is a "position"? If not, how does this violate your definition of "position".

Comment: @KeithMcClary I'm not sure, but that wouldn't fourier transform to the momentum basis and so it wouldn't relate to the uncertainty principle. I suppose the need for an infinite basis with their dirac deltas is based on that.

Comment: What about a particle that can be found in either the left or the right half of a box?

Answer (score 1):

We know that for any system, the position and momentum satisfy the commutation  relation
$$[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar $$
Take the trace of the both hand side
$$\text{Tr}(\hat{x}\hat{p}-\hat{p}\hat{x})=i\hbar\text{Tr} (I)$$
$$0=i\hbar \text{Tr}\ (I)\ \ !!! $$
It's clear that such a commutation relation can't be satisfied for finite-dimensional cases. Thus the operator these operators $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ live in infinite dimensional space.

Comment: This is fair but you are already implicitly assuming that you have a continuous position (which allows for classical momentum to be defined and thus, allows for the commutator relations to follow from the Poisson bracket between position and momentum). One can imagine a particle on a compact lattice structure, the position operator for such a particle would have a finite-dimensional representation.

Comment: How would you take the trace for the infinite case? Why would it not be zero ?

Comment: @barrett-barry Use the property $\text{Tr} (\Omega \Lambda )=\text{Tr}\Omega \text{Tr}\Lambda$. It's not zero since trace of identity is not zero.

Comment: @DvijD.C. A finite-dimensional representation means that you have a finite eigenvalues, That is the system can be found in the states of the form $|x=x_0\rangle $. These are not physically realizable since this corresponds to plane wave in momentum space.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi That's not what it means and the rest of what you say doesn't address my comment. A finite dimensional representation means the number of dimensions of the Hilbert space is finite, or, the number of eigenvalues is finite -- not that the eigenvalues are finite in value.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi Tr$(AB)\ne $Tr$(A)$Tr$(B)$ always.  See this section: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product for a counter example but this is irrelevant anyways for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit what you mean but there are meaningful definitions of *discrete phase space*, where operators are labelled by discrete (and cyclic) indices that can be interpreted as position and momentum.

The simplest example is spin.  You can label
\begin{align}
\sigma_z\to \sigma_{10}\, ,\qquad \sigma_x\to \sigma_{01}, 
\qquad \sigma_{0}:=\mathbb{1}\to \sigma_{00}\, ,\qquad 
\sigma_y\to \sigma_{11}
\end{align}
so that, up to constant factors
\begin{align}
\sigma_{a_1b_1}\sigma_{a_2b_2}\propto \sigma_{a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2} \, ,\tag{1}
\end{align}
where addition is taken modulo $2$.  Moreover, it turns out that the eigenstates of $\sigma_{10}$ and $\sigma_{01}$ are "complementary" in the sense that the modulus square of the overlap $\vert\langle \psi^{a_1,b_2}_{k}\vert \psi^{a_2,b_2}_j\rangle\vert^2=\frac{1}{2}$ is constant and independent of the choice of eigenstates.  Thus, if you prepare a system in the state $\vert\psi^{0,1}_j\rangle$, you know nothing about the outcomes of the "complementary" operator $\sigma_{1,0}$ since every measurement outcome of $\sigma_{1,0}$ is equally probable.  This is the discrete version of "knowing the position exactly means you know nothing about the momentum".  The eigenstate of $\sigma_{01}$ are related to those of $\sigma_{10}$ by a Fourier-transform.  Here, position and momentum can be taken to be the eigenvalues of $\sigma_{10}$ and $\sigma_{01}$, or taken to be in the set $\{0,1\}$ (by simple shift).  Either way, the "position" and "momentum" are discrete and the eigenstates live in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space.

You can search GoogleScholar for "discrete phase space" and you'll come up with additional examples.  This is closely related to the notion of mutually unbiased bases, on which there is considerable literature.

The construction used for the Pauli matrices can be generalized whenever the dimension $d$ is a prime number.  The property (1) generalizes (modulo $d$) for the generalized Pauli group as discussed in

> Patera J, Zassenhaus H. The Pauli matrices in n dimensions and finest gradings of simple Lie algebras of type $A_{n− 1}$. Journal of Mathematical Physics. 1988 Mar;29(3):665-73.

If $d$ is a power of a prime, such as $d=4=2^2$ or $d=9=3^2$, then one must use finite fields (not the fields of quantum field theory or electric field, but [algebraic finite field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)).  This discrete phase space picture was initially proposed in

> Gibbons KS, Hoffman MJ, Wootters WK. Discrete phase space based on finite fields. Physical Review A. 2004 Dec 3;70(6):062101.

If $d$ is a composite, such as $d=6=2\times 3$, the problem of constructing a discrete phase space and associated complete set of mutually unbiased bases is unsolved although heroic attempts have been made, as in

> Brierley S, Weigert S. Constructing mutually unbiased bases in dimension six. Physical Review A. 2009 May 14;79(5):052316.

The *grading structure* of (1) has also been exploited in the $d\to\infty$ limit, in

> Zeitlin V. Finite-mode analogs of 2D ideal hydrodynamics: Coadjoint orbits and local canonical structure. Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena. 1991 Apr 2;49(3):353-62.